# How to hide multiple recipient email addresses laravel send mail

Tags: php, laravel, email

i use laravel Mail function to send html mail to multiple email 
i create array of emails the message sent sucsessfully to all users but in the top of email message show all email addresses users ,
how to fix this problem how to use use `cc` or `bcc` in array of emails ?

```
 $product = Product::find($request->product_id)->get()->first();
     $emailUsers = User::select('email')->pluck('email')->toArray();
     $emailSubscribers = NewsLetter::select('email')->pluck('email')->toArray();
     $emails =array_unique(array_merge($emailUsers,$emailSubscribers), SORT_REGULAR);
     $end_at = Carbon::parse($request->end_at, 'UTC')->format('d/m/Y');
       $data = array(
          'name' =>$request->name,
          'product_name' =>$product->name,
          'product_img' =>$product->poster,
          'discount' =>$request->discount,
          'price_with_discount' =>$request->price_with_discount,
          'price_without_discount' =>$product->price,
          'start_at' =>$request->start_at,
          'end_at' =>$end_at,
          'description' =>$request->description
       );
       Mail::send('front-office.mails.promotion-letters.mail-promo', $data, function ($message) use($request,$emails) {
            $message->from('team@testemail.com','test');
            $message->to($emails)->subject
              ('Nouvelles promotion  !!');
       });
```

Comment: Use a foreach loop to send to each user individually.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does support the following type on construct that might help you (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#sending-mail) ...

```php
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->cc($moreUsers)
    ->bcc($evenMoreUsers)
    ->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

And the bcc() part will hide the recipients emails.

Comment: but i want to send email of tow different  tables users and subscribers

Comment: You can add the visible emails in the to() or the cc() and the hidden email addresses in the bcc(). Unless I am not understanding what you mean by "send email of tow different tables"

Comment: i get email to sent from tow tables  and i use array_merge to get one array has all emails

Comment: In that case, how to you know which email addresses you want to hide? I don't get it.

Comment: This is not possible, In your case you will have to loop trough each address and send the mail separately. If you want to send all at once bcc is the only option